# Distinguish Between Default and User Input in Sudoku HTML

Tags: html, css, web, sudoku

I am taking my first web programming course but the instructor isn't much help. After trying to contact him for that past week I decided to look through the web for help and guidance. 
My question is: how can I distinguish between the programmed Sudoku numbers and the empty cells that the user needs to fill in? Preferably, I would like to make the programmed cells to have a gray background while the empty cells to have no formatting.

Currently in my css file I have this:

```
table {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
table-layout: fixed;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td{
    border-top-width: 3px;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
    border-left-width: 3px;
}

td:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(6), td:nth-child(9){
    border-right-width: 3px;

}

tr:nth-child(3) td, tr:nth-child(6) td, tr:nth-child(9) td{
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
}
```

Here is my html file (not final formatting but gives an idea):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Start Timer</td>
            <td>Reset Timer </td>
            <td>Timer:_________.</td>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

***EDIT***
So I added this to my CSS file and it actually works but I don't get why. Is this recommended. I know there is probably a handful of solutions to my question but is this an actual solution or did I get lucky that my project is actually working.

```
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: gray;
    font-weight: bold;
    empty-cells:
}

td:empty {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add 2 class to td fill and empty
and if it cell is fill add class "fill" to it

```
td.fill{
    background: #000;
}
td.empty{
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work. I posted my html file. Maybe I have an error else where that is preventing me from using this. At any rate, I appreciate your help.

Comment: can you add to empty td class "empty" ?